# Function is returning promise object

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I got this function

```
module.exports.usersdb = async function (req, res) {

    const arr = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];

    const encodearray = arr.map(data=> _token.signToken(data));

    console.log(encodearray);
}
```

but the output is a promise object like: "Promise: {result}"

How can i get it as a string?

this is the signtoken function which is exported

```
exports.signToken = function (data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        try {

            const token = jwt.sign(data, _sign, algorithm);
            resolve(token)

        } catch (err) {

            return reject("An error has occurred " + err)

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Why are you using promises when you're not using any asynchronous code? You're using the synchronous version of `jwt.sign()`.

Comment: I think you should be good to go if you use await the response of _token.SignToken function

Comment: `encodearray` looks like an array of promises.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all